# Results Repeat When Using Nested while Loops in PHP

Tags: php, json, nested-loops

I am developing an API using PHP, which gives results in JSON. The thing is the results repeat in every array. You will get a better idea of what I am trying to say if you check [Here](http://projects.base29.com/webservice/?q=projects).

And this is my code:

```
<?php

function requiredData()
{
    $db = $this->dbConnection();
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects JOIN project_details ON projects.project_id=project_details.project_id";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects LIMIT 10";
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects,project_details WHERE projects.project_id=project_details .project_id";

    $queryResult = $db->query($sql);

    if ($queryResult->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while ($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $pid = $row['project_id'];
            $detailsql = "SELECT * FROM project_details WHERE project_id=$pid LIMIT 10";
            $sqlResult = $db->query($detailsql);
            if ($sqlResult->num_rows > 0)
            {
                while ($d = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $r[] = array(
                        "project_id" => $d['project_id'],
                        "project_detail" => array(
                            "work_done" => $d['project_detail'],
                            "payment_status" => $d['project_payment_status'],
                            "detail_id" => $d['project_detail_id']
                        )
                    );
                }
            }

            $results[$row['project_name']] = array(
                "project_id" => $row["project_id"],
                "project_start_date" => $row["project_start_date"],
                "project_due_date" => $row["project_due_date"],
                "project_currency" => $row["project_currency"],
                "project_work_details" => $r
            );
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: _"The thing is the results repeat in every array."_ and I assume it isn't suppose to do that? Could you clarify the issue? Perhaps generate an expected output and how it's showing now? (Please don't post a wall of examples but a shortened down version)

Comment: if you see in the description I have posted a link which will take you to the generated output ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tweaking with the code and made to work ... Here is my code ... If someone is having the same issue they can take my code as a reference.

```
function requiredData() {

    $db = $this->dbConnection();
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects JOIN project_details ON projects.project_id=project_details.project_id";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects LIMIT 10";
    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects,project_details WHERE projects.project_id=project_details .project_id";

    $queryResult = $db->query($sql);

    if ($queryResult->num_rows > 0) {

        $results = array();


        while ($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()) {

            $pid = $row['project_id'];
            //$detailsql = "SELECT * FROM projects p INNER JOIN project_details d ON p.project_id=d.project_id WHERE p.project_id={$pid} LIMIT 10";


            $detailsql = "SELECT * FROM project_details WHERE project_id = $pid";
            $sqlResult = $db->query($detailsql);


            $results[$pid] = array(
                "project_name" => $row['project_name'],
                "project_id" => $row["project_id"],
                "project_start_date" => $row["project_start_date"],
                "project_due_date" => $row["project_due_date"],
                "project_currency" => $row["project_currency"],
                "project_details" => array()
            );


            if ($sqlResult->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($d = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $results[$pid]['project_details'][] = array(
                               "project_detail" => array(
                                "detail_id" => $d['project_detail_id'],
                                "work_done" => $d['project_detail'],
                                "work_payment" => $d['project_payment'],
                                "payment_status" => $d['project_payment_status']
                            )
                        );

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: I see you marked your own post as an answer after you *tried* to take my advice. No big deal, but NO ONE would take the advice of your code. I am not trying to offend you, but un-necessarily nesting queries is a big, big no-no. Using PHP to nest-join queries instead of using MySQL to do it is the same as relying on JavaScript to do the work that you should have used PHP for. Please learn to use JOIN's (if you dont already). Life will get 100000000000x times easier when developing. I promise.

Answer (score 0):

This may not *really* help you, but I would probably change your code to use JOIN's instead of nesting queries.

Obviously, you should choose either a RIGHT, LEFT, INNER or OUTER join depending on what data you want returned, how and when. But without knowing more about your project... This is what I would do. Leave the recursion, association and heavy lifting to the database engine. That's what it's job is.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM projects p INNER JOIN project_details d ON p.ID=d.project_id WHERE p.ID={$pid}"; 
    $res = mysql_query($sql); 
    if ($res) { 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
     /* Handle row processing using $row['column'] */ 
    } 
}
```